# Calling a service but description of the return code does not match what I define explicitly

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am using OpenAPI (Swagger) to define a web service.

In the response section, I define the following code explicitly

```
responses:
  '200':
    description: Your order has been placed
    content: ...
```

However, when I call the service, it returns "200 OK", which is a standard http status code description instead of the description I define explicitly

According to here https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/, it says "If a response range is defined using an explicit code, the explicit code definition takes precedence over the range definition for that code."

Do I miss/misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `description` field in the OpenAPI definition is metadata used for documentation purposes only.

This description is not related to the [status text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#http_responses) (aka [`reason-phrase`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2)) value in HTTP responses, such as "OK" in "HTTP/1.1 200 OK". Most servers/frameworks use common status text e.g. "200 OK" or "403 Forbidden".

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Got it ^_^